# R script to connect to Azure Devops, pull, transform & merge data from Azure Devops with other resources into Power BI

Tags: r, azure-devops, powerbi

My company is transitioning from TFS on-premises to TFS Azure Devops.  We have several Power BI R scripts that utilize R to connect to the TFS_Warehouse DB (on the old version) & other sources and transform the data before further manipulating & presenting the reports data with Power BI.  Now that we will be migrating to Azure Devops, my understanding is there is no back-end database to which I can connect to pull the TFS data.

My question is:  Is there a function/set of functions in R that allows one to connect to the Azure Devops Analytics Views so that the data transformations & data merges with other resources can still be made in R prior to further manipulation in Power BI?  If so, can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

> Transitioning from TFS on-premises to TFS Azure Devops

If the target server you mentioned is still TFS(**Azure Devops server 2019**) rather than **Azure Devops service**, you don't need worry about there's no Back-end database can for your server use. For Azure Devops server 2019, the database still available for it. You can still use previous R script to fetch and transform the data.

---

But, if the server you are transit to is **Azure Devops service**, or you hope there has R functions which can connect to the Analytics Views in **Azure Devops server 2019**, unfortunate to say, No, until now we have not expand this function(s) into the R packages.

No matter it is **Azure DevOps Services** or **Azure DevOps Server 2019**, we all provide the [Power BI Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/?view=azure-devops) with them. But, this does not support merge the data from other resource.

As a work around, I recommend you fetch the data from Azure Devops into Excel first, then use [Power query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d) which can combine the data from different resource to combine these data with another source.

We just publish the feature for integrating PowerBI with Azure DevOps Analytics, for user to get more customized operation and data sources, expand the connection to another data source should be a good feature.

You can raise a suggestion feature ticket to our [official suggestion forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22). Our PM will review these suggestions regularly, and consider to choose features that are more conducive to giving users a better experience into our Roadmap.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Fetching the data into excel first then using power query to combine the data is a lot more work than clicking a button and processing the data directly through Power BI via a script and auto-updating the visualizations immediately.  I appreciate that possibly could be the only option, but it's disappointing to hear.

Comment: @RCQAAccount We are trying to improve and expand our feature to let users have better experience with it. If convenient, very appreciate you can raise this suggestion into our user voice forum. Our PM would review them seriously.